# TypeError: store.getState is not a function React-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a login form and it requires me to migrate my soloreac app in react + redux app. I'm facing many errors and stuck with `TypeError: store.getState is not a function`. I'm a newbie in this, any kind of help will be appriciated.

Index.js file

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Provider from "react-redux/es/components/Provider";
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";
import * as promise from 'redux-promise';

// ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

const createstorewithmiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createstorewithmiddleware}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'),
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js file:

```
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch, Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.scss';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

import Home from "./screens/home";
import SignInScreen from "./screens/signInScreen";
import SignUpScreen from "./screens/signUpScreen";
import {checkUser} from "./actions/auth";


const loading = () => <div className="animated fadeIn pt-3 text-center">Loading...</div>;

// Containers
const DefaultLayout = React.lazy(() => import('./containers/DefaultLayout'));

// Pages
const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Login'));

const Register = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Register'));
const Page404 = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Page404'));
const Page500 = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Page500'));

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.checkUser();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
          <Switch>
            {/*<Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props}/>} />*/}
            <Route exact path="/sign-in/" component={SignInScreen}/>
            <Route exact path="/sign-up/" component={SignUpScreen}/>

            {/*<Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" render={props => <Register {...props}/>} />*/}
            <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" render={props => <Page404 {...props}/>} />
            <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" render={props => <Page500 {...props}/>} />
            <Route path="/" name="Home" render={props => <DefaultLayout {...props}/>} />
          </Switch>
        </React.Suspense>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  checkUser: () => dispatch(checkUser())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I get this error. I don't understand what file or code is causing this error.

> TypeError: store.getState is not a function
>   new Provider
>   node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js:25
>     22 |     store: store,
>     23 |     subscription: subscription
>     24 |   };
>   25 |   _this.previousState = store.getState();
>        | ^  26 |   return _this;
>     27 | }
>     28 | 
>   View compiled
>   constructClassInstance
>   node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11787
>     11784 |     new ctor(props, context); // eslint-disable-line no-new
>     11785 |   }
>     11786 | }
>   11787 | var instance = new ctor(props, context);
>           | ^  11788 | var state = workInProgress.memoizedState = instance.state !== null && instance.state !== undefined ? instance.state : null;
>     11789 | adoptClassInstance(workInProgress, instance);
>     11790 | {

Comment: `import Provider from "react-redux/es/components/Provider"` seems off.  Can you just do `import Provider from "react-redux"`

Comment: @ChristopherNgo ```Attempted import error: 'react-redux' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Provider').``` getting this error

Comment: oh my bad thats meant to be `import { Provider } from "react-redux"`

Comment: Did that already, still same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try initiate your store differently:

```
const createstorewithmiddleware = createStore(yourReducer, applyMiddleware(promise))
```